# why this JavaScript algorithm got undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to solve this problem :

> You are going to be given an array of integers.  Your job is to take that array and find an index N where the sum of the integers to the
> left of N is equal to the sum of the integers to the right of N. If
> there is no index that would make this happen, return -1.
>
> **For example:**
>
> Let's say you are given the array `{1,2,3,4,3,2,1}`: Your function
> will return the index 3, because at the 3rd position of the array, the
> sum of left side of the index `({1,2,3})` and the sum of the right
> side of the index `({3,2,1})` both equal 6. Let's look at another one.
>
> You are given the array `{1,100,50,-51,1,1}`: Your function will
> return the index 1, because at the 1st position of the array, the sum
> of left side of the index `({1})` and the sum of the right side of the
> index `({50,-51,1,1})` both equal 1. Last one:
>
> You are given the array `{20,10,-80,10,10,15,35}` At index 0 the left
> side is `{}` The right side is `{10,-80,10,10,15,35}` They both are
> equal to 0 when added. (Empty arrays are equal to 0 in this problem)
> Index 0 is the place where the left side and right side are equal.
>
> **Note:** Please remember that in most programming/scripting languages the index of an array starts at 0. Input: An integer array of length
> `0 < arr < 1000`. The numbers in the array can be any integer positive
> or negative. Output: The lowest index N where the side to the left of
> N is equal to the side to the right of N. If you do not find an index
> that fits these rules, then you will return -1. Note: If you are given
> an array with multiple answers, return the lowest correct index.

**I answer with this code :**

```
 function findEvenIndex(arr) {
  var index;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.lenght; i++) {
    if (arr.slice(0,i+1).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) == arr.slice(i + 1 ,).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)) 
{
      index = i;
    }
  }
  return index;
}
```

*but the problem is that function return : undefined; when I'm trying to test it.*

**My questions are:**

-why the function got : undefined?

-how can I fix it?

**Note:** the link of the exercice"https://www.codewars.com/kata/5679aa472b8f57fb8c000047/train/javascript"

Thanks

---

Comment: `lenght`? Did you mean `length`? Also, if the `if` condition is never true, the result will be `undefined` nonetheless. Usually, if an index cannot be found, `-1` should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer. Your mistakes are:

1. incorrect spelling of `length`.
2. incorrect iteration of array `arr.slice(i)` reversely.

```html
 function findEvenIndex(arr) {
  let index = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let start = arr.slice(0, i+1).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    let end = arr.slice(i).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
    
    if (start === end) {
      
      index = i
    }
    
  }
  return index;
}
```